# How to update existing record and insert new record at same time in SQL table ? ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have a table.I want to update the table.Actually I have a gridview which retrieve values from SQL table.When page load then gridview load the values .I want that when i insert new values in gridview then in SQL Table existing values update and also new values insert in the same table using SINGLE query.How can i do this?Just tell me SQL query which works in C#,ASP.NET.I'm asking for UPDATE existing record and insert new record in the same table at same time using one query. Thanks

```
public void insert(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string user = Session["name"].ToString();
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HAMEED_KHAN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db_compiler;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT User_ID from tbl_user WHERE User_Name='" + user + "'", cnn);
cnn.Open();
string id = cmd3.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
int ID = Int32.Parse(id);
Session["ID"] = ID;
string d = Session["value"].ToString();
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Database_id FROM Create_db WHERE Database_Name='" + d + "'", cnn);
Response.Write("<script>Var Z=Prompt('Enter Table Name');</script>");
string dbid = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
cnn.Close();
int D_ID = Int32.Parse(dbid);
string str = "";
string type = "";
for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
str = GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
type = GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text.ToString();
 string Name = GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
 string Type = GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text.ToString();
 string size = GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text.ToString();
 CheckBox allow = GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
 CheckBox primary = GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[5].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
 string UserID = Session["ID"].ToString();
int UID = Int32.Parse(UserID);
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
string A = (allow.Checked == true ? "NULL" : "NOT NULL");
string P = (primary.Checked == true ? "PRIMARY KEY" : "");
string Table = Session["TBL_NAME"].ToString();
string queryy ="USE db_compiler UPDATE tbl_field SET Column_Name='" + Name + "', Data_Type='" + Type + "',Size='" + size + "',Database_id='" + D_ID + "',Allow_Null_='" + (allow.Checked == true ? "true" : "false") + "',Primary_Key_='" + (primary.Checked == true ? "true" : "false") + "',User_id='" + UID + "',Date='" + date + "' WHERE Table_Name='" + Table + "' IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 insert into tbl_field (Table_Name,Column_Name,Data_Type,Size,Database_id,Allow_Null_,Primary_Key_,User_id,Date) VALUES('" + Table + "','" + Name + "','" + Type + "','" + size + "','" + D_ID + "','" + (allow.Checked == true ? "true" : "false") + "','" + (primary.Checked == true ? "true" : "false") + "','" + UID + "','" + date + "')";
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryy, cnn);
 SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 cnn.Open();
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 cnn.Close();
 }
 }
```

Here is my grid view image[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13f8O.png) Table name is `employee` first i have 3 rows in grid view `Name`,`id`,'address' when i insert new row `ph` and click on `update table` then i update all rows with `ph` [Db-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyNNj.png)

Comment: Sounds like you really want to create an update trigger in the database. Other than that you'll need two statements, possibly in a transaction.

Comment: I can't use two transaction because if i use `insert` statement first then data will be overirde and if use `update` statement first then when user enter new `column` and press `updateTable` button then new column will not be found in existing table then i can't update

Comment: I don't want trigger i want just when user click on `updateTable` button then all values in the `gridview` replace the old values and also insert new value in the same table.Simple.